# Why are there so few Hellenic languages when there are so many Romance languages?

Tags: latin, greek, history

Both Greece and Rome had huge empires and Greek was even used to administer the Eastern Roman Empire. Christian scriptures are even primarily written in Greek.
So why are there so many Romance languages and so few Hellenic ones in the modern world?

Comment: Do you mean, why are modern Hellenic languages considered to be dialects whereas modern Romance languages are considered to be separate languages? Are Lombardi, Tuscan and Friulian dialects of one language?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Muslim_conquests

Comment: @user6726 Tsakonian & Griko are not infrequently called a separate language in academic literature. I've also occasionally seen Pontic & Mariupolitan and Cappadocian Greek referred to as distinct languages

Comment: And another duplicate: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9656/9781

Comment: @Sir Cornflakes    This ***is*** a duplicate, and its answers almost certainly answer this one. There are not that many  political entities at present running on [Hellenic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenic_languages), so these are classified as dialects. Viz [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46733/why-are-there-so-few-hellenic-languages-when-there-are-so-many-romance-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1).